# Call to undefined function __()

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I am working with Wordpress and Laravel simultaneously.

The problem is that they share a common function name ( function __() ). So I changed its name in Laravel:

[project folder]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php

(line 938 and 947)

It was __() and now is ___().

And ran "composer update".

Now, Laravel and Wordpress run without any (percievable) problems. But every time I run a page in Laravel, the log prints "Call to undefined function __()".

Here's the stack trace:

```
[2019-06-27 11:43:50] local.ERROR: Call to undefined function __() (View: C:\MyFolder\MyDevProjects\Laravel\projetofm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\views\404.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Call to undefined function __() (View: C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\views\\404.blade.php) at C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\storage\\framework\\views\\aef0b3ffdea5390a3697c2a0ec0b280e5440e2f8.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined function __() at C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\storage\\framework\\views\\aef0b3ffdea5390a3697c2a0ec0b280e5440e2f8.php:2)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine.php(47): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError), 1)
#1 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\\\MyFolder\\\\MyD...', Array)
#2 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(142): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('C:\\\\MyFolder\\\\MyD...', Array)
#3 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(125): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#4 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(90): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#5 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Response.php(42): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#6 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php(202): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#7 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory.php(55): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), 404, Array)
#8 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory.php(81): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->make(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), 404, Array)
#9 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(380): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->view('errors::404', Array, 404, Array)
#10 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(289): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException))
#11 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(188): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException))
#12 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(49): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException))
#13 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(83): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException))
#14 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException))
#15 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\MyFolder\\MyDevProjects\\Laravel\\projetofm\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\MyFolder\\\\MyD...')
#35 {main}
"}
```

I thought "composer update" would update the variable's name throughout the project.

How can I change the variable's name without creating these kind of conflicts?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm just curious.. how do you work with both of them simultaneously?

Comment: `I thought "composer update" would update the variable's name throughout the project.` No idea where you got that idea from. You would manually need to change all the instances of use everywhere that uses the Laravel version. And then you'll need to do the same change every time there's a new Laravel version, or you'd need to support a copy of Laravel yourself.

Comment: @MateiMihai Sorry man. It would be too long to explain here.

Comment: @Jonnix I got taht idea from here: https://github.com/laraish/laraish/issues/1

Comment: Are you using Laraish?

Comment: @Jonnix No. I'm doing it the other way around. It's not Laravel in Wordpress. It's Wordpress in Laravel (literally, in the public folder). The reason is, we just want to use a Wordpress specific plugin as a temporary solution for our project. We'll recreate it from scratch in Laravel (with even more features) in the future. But, for now, we'll use it like this. Can't I just namespace the project somehow and isolate these definitions?

Comment: is it possible that WordPress has not been initialised yet, so `__()` is not yet defined for Laravel?

Comment: @MateiMihai [Themosis](https://framework.themosis.com/) allows you to work with WordPress in a Laravel environment.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I found the solution. I updated an answer. @MateiMihai, thanks for the suggestion. I searched for something similar for a whole morning, but couldn't find anything. I'll try it if I ever need to integrate WordPress in laravel again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jonnix, I simply followed the error logs and changed all function calls.

It ended up changing only these two files:

> [project
>   folder]\storage\framework\views\f1c5ee6d0afdfec4e103d6083eba089e6f755b96.php
>
> [project
>   folder]\storage\framework\views\aef0b3ffdea5390a3697c2a0ec0b280e5440e2f8.php

As pointed out by Jonnix, this is not an ideal solution. I'll need to maintain these function calls everytime I update Laravel.

For the scope of this problem though, since it is a temporary "hack", this solution will do perfectly.

In retrospective, I should have used a framework like [Themosis](https://framework.themosis.com/) to integrate Wordpress in Laravel, as suggested by MateiMihai.

Answer (score 0):

i use

```
{{ trans('my_file_in_my_lang_folder.my_phrase') }}
```

method instead of

```
{{ __(file.phrase) }}
```

__ method and its worked for me .

my laravel version

```
 php artisan --version
```

> Laravel Framework version 5.2.20

double check:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /es
            messages.php
```